# calendar.getTime().equals(cal1) return false though both calendars has same time

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.calendar

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (calendar.getTime().equals(cal1.getTime())) {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
```

Printing `calendar.getTime()` and `cal1.getTime()` returns

Mon Aug 10 16:00:10 IST 2020
Mon Aug 10 16:00:11 IST 2020

Following code works as expected printing `Hi!` it should be return true for equals check but it doesn't.

```
    if (!calendar.getTime().after(cal1.getTime()) || !calendar.getTime().before(cal1.getTime())) {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
```

Then why it is returning false for equals check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Mon Aug 10 16:00:10 IST 2020` and `Mon Aug 10 16:00:11 IST 2020` differ in seconds.**

Also, I suggest you do not use the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API. Use the [modern date time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) instead as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr1 = "Mon Aug 10 16:00:10 IST 2020";
        String dateTimeStr2 = "Mon Aug 10 16:00:11 IST 2020";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z u", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr1, formatter);
        LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, formatter);

        System.out.println(date1.equals(date2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

## How to compare them by excluding seconds:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr1 = "Mon Aug 10 16:00:10 IST 2020";
        String dateTimeStr2 = "Mon Aug 10 16:00:11 IST 2020";

        // Define the formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z u", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Parse the date-time strings into LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr1, formatter);
        LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, formatter);

        // Create LocalDateTime instances from the parsed ones by excluding seconds
        LocalDateTime date1WithoutSec = LocalDateTime.of(date1.toLocalDate(),
                LocalTime.of(date1.getHour(), date1.getMinute()));
        LocalDateTime date2WithoutSec = LocalDateTime.of(date2.toLocalDate(),
                LocalTime.of(date2.getHour(), date2.getMinute()));

        System.out.println(date1WithoutSec.equals(date2WithoutSec));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Comment: Instead of changing API I tried this and it worked as expected.          `calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);`
       `calendar1.setTimeInMillis(0);`

Comment: @Hemlata - You should stop using the poorly designed legacy date-time API. Learn the new API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: @A Thanks I'm going to switch to it.

Comment: An answer with a lot of good information. Your way of getting rid of the seconds is unnecessarily low level. I suggest `LocalDateTime date1WithoutSec = date1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);` (similar for date 2).

Comment: @Hemlata Your trick with `setTimeInMillis()` makes sure that the objects are *always* equal even if they were centuries apart from the outset. The confusing design of `Calendar` didn’t make this clear. With java.time it will be a lot harder to make a similar mistake. I do encourage your migration to java.time.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks a lot. I was checking if it is not equal then don't enable button if equals then do. I've already switched to `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal at all and you can see.

Mon Aug 10 16:00:***10*** IST 2020

Mon Aug 10 16:00:***11*** IST 2020.

And your second if has `or` in it so it returns `true`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't noticed seconds .

Comment: @ So let me know how can I avoid seconds when checking equals?